# Kafka Connection error in contoller.logs

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using single node Kafka(v 0.10.2) and single node zookeeper (v 3.4.8) and my controller.log file is filled with this exception

```
java.io.IOException: Connection to 1 was disconnected before the response was read
    at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.$anonfun$blockingSendAndReceive$3(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:114)
    at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.$anonfun$blockingSendAndReceive$3$adapted(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:112)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.$anonfun$blockingSendAndReceive$1(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:112)
    at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.recursivePoll$1(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:136)
    at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.pollContinuously$extension(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:142)
    at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.blockingSendAndReceive$extension(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:108)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.liftedTree1$1(ControllerChannelManager.scala:192)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:184)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
```

I googled this exception but was not able to find the root cause for this exception. Can someone suggest me why this error is happening and how to prevent it?

Comment: It means that the controller was waiting for a response from broker 1 and didn't get one. It's surprising to see this in a single node setup so you are probably having a GC pause or running a workload but appropriate for the setup because this is the JVM not being able to talk to itself efficiently.

Comment: @dawsaw yes on that single node cluster(8 cores,16 GB RAM) I am having approx 500 GB data. 280 topics with avg 100 partitions per topic .So can you suggest some way fix this .and can you tell me how to determine that your node is overloaded?

Comment: 28000 partitions is way too many. Try reducing that number to something closer to 2000 max for a single node

Comment: @dawsaw Can you tell me how this partition number is decided . Which resource is causing the bottleneck . I am having (8 cores and 16 GB RAM with 1TB SSD)

Comment: The partition number is configured at the topic level and the broker configuration has a default for automatically created topics. The reason this many partitions causes the controller problems is outlined here https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-choose-the-number-of-topicspartitions-in-a-kafka-cluster/

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter same issue in multi-node cluster scenario. It was because of connection shutdown between kafka-node and zookeeper. I would suggest to restart zookeeper server then kafka-node to re-establish the connection therefore broker should be handle pub/sub message transition.
Hope it would raise you from this.